# Overload/Override SQLDataSource Update Events

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a `SqlDataSource` that loads/selects the User and role information from an ASP.net side quite well. I like the ability to take advantage of the auto generated edit/update link buttons that are formed (the edit event seems perfectly fine, and I'd love to be able to use it).

But, given what I [learned yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187128/crud-3-inner-joined-tables-cleanly-with-sql-server/32188545?noredirect=1#comment52263489_32188545) about how I should Insert/Delete into the `AspNetUserRoles` table, I was wanting to wrap the update of `AspNetUsers` and the Insert/Delete queries into one transaction.

I was able to get the code to work if I assigned a sub to the `GridView.RowUpdating` event, but then the "main" update command from the `SqlDataSource` seems to fire after the fact.

Is there a way to override the automatically generated `SqlDataSource` events? I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680153/gridview-rowupdating-sqldatasource-update-from-codebehind), but it doesn't really get at what I'm trying to do.

I think because I'm trying to update two tables, and for one table use Insert/Delete commands, and because I need to manipulate the variables taking values from the edited row (to lookup the `RoleID` from the `RoleName`), that I really need to override it.

So far I've only [found](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-cs) [examples](http://forums.asp.net/t/1134441.aspx?GridView%20Overriding%20Update%20Delete%20Events) of people who really [didn't need to override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680153/gridview-rowupdating-sqldatasource-update-from-codebehind) the auto-generated scripts, not an example where someone did.  In that case, is there a way to change the initial set up for this?  I would think not, but perhaps I'm wrong.

Below are the `GridView` and `SqlDataSource` I'm using. I think my actual sub is fine because it fires correctly, just not instead of the update command (shoots to soon joke here).

```
<asp:GridView ID="URdataGridView" runat="server" 
     AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="MainUser" ForeColor="#333333" 
     GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="Id">
     <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
     <Columns>
         <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" ReadOnly="True" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" SortExpression="UserName" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="PhoneNumber" HeaderText="PhoneNumber" SortExpression="PhoneNumber" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
         <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="LockoutEnabled" HeaderText="LockoutEnabled" SortExpression="LockoutEnabled" />
     </Columns>
     <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
     <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
     <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
     <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
     <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
     <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
     <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
     <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
     <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
     <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="MainUser" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" 
     DeleteCommand="DeleteUserOnlyQuery" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
     SelectCommand="SelectUsersRoles" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
     UpdateCommand="UpdateUserOnlyQuery" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Id" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Email" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_UserName" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_PhoneNumber" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_LockoutEnabled" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_Id" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PhoneNumber" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="LockoutEnabled" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to override the `Update`. For that you need to subscribe to the [Updating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event, do whatever you want and then either cancel the DB operation, or just proceed. In code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="MainUser" runat="server"
                   OnUpdating="MainUser_Updating"
                   ...

protected void MainUser_Updating(Object source, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // here run your custom logic
    // perhaps use e.Command to see parameters and such
    // you can even do DB updates here manually

    // ....

    // if you still want initial DB update to occur, simply do nothing in the end
    // if however you need to cancel the DB operation, indicate that
    e.Cancel = true;        
}
```

Comment: So really this is before the `Update`, and by calling `e.Cancel`, I'm just killing any future action?

Comment: Also, I think you want `e` to be `SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs` right?

Comment: @AtlLED, yes, you are killing action that SqlDataSource was going to do on DB. And thanks for the catch, updated